# Convert collection of hash maps to a csv file

Tags: clojure

I have the following collection of hash maps:

```
{a:"Completed" b:1 c:"Friday" d:4}
{a:"Started" b:1 c:"Monday" d:4}
{a:"In Progress" b:1 c:"Sunday" d:1}
{a:"Completed" b:3 c:"Tuesday" d:9}
```

How can I convert this to a CSV file in clojure?

i.e.

```
a,b,c,d
Completed,1,Friday,4
Started,1,Monday,4
In Progress,1,Sunday,1
Completed,3,Tuesday,9
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/clojure/data.csv

Comment: Just a small remark, your hashmaps are not in  edn (Clojure) notation, but JSON. See https://github.com/edn-format/edn

Answer (score 19):

You didn't explicitly say you were starting with JSON, but let's assume you are.
I would use [cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire)
to parse your JSON string to get, in this case, a vector of maps
representing your data. We'll assume you've done that for sake
of simplicity and just use a `var` called `data` to avoid
cluttering the example.

Now we can create a vector of vectors, then use
[clojure.data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv) to save the
results to a file.

You can try this out at the REPL using [lein try](https://github.com/rkneufeld/lein-try).
Follow the setup instructions for `lein try` if you don't already have it, then run
`lein try clojure.data.csv 0.1.2`. Once you're in a REPL with this dependency:

```
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv] '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(def data
  [{:a "Completed"   :b 1 :c "Friday"  :d 4}
   {:a "Started"     :b 1 :c "Monday"  :d 4}
   {:a "In Progress" :b 1 :c "Sunday"  :d 1}
   {:a "Completed"   :b 3 :c "Tuesday" :d 9}])

(defn write-csv [path row-data]
  (let [columns [:a :b :c :d]
        headers (map name columns)
        rows (mapv #(mapv % columns) row-data)]
    (with-open [file (io/writer path)]
      (csv/write-csv file (cons headers rows)))))

(write-csv "/tmp/results.csv" data)
```

Now you can see the results of your handiwork:

```
$ cat /tmp/results.csv
a,b,c,d
Completed,1,Friday,4
Started,1,Monday,4
In Progress,1,Sunday,1
Completed,3,Tuesday,9
```

Answer (score 4):

I read all the answers but I wanted more generic and reusable solution.

Here is what I came up with. You can use `write-csv` and `maps->csv-data` independently or together via `write-csv-from-maps`. More importantly, you don't need to hard code headers. Just pass your vector of maps and you should be all set.

A. DIY Approach

```
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn write-csv 
  "Takes a file (path, name and extension) and 
   csv-data (vector of vectors with all values) and
   writes csv file."
  [file csv-data] 
  (with-open [writer (io/writer file)]
    (csv/write-csv writer csv-data)))

 (defn maps->csv-data 
  "Takes a collection of maps and returns csv-data 
   (vector of vectors with all values)."       
   [maps]
   (let [columns (-> maps first keys)
         headers (mapv name columns)
         rows (mapv #(mapv % columns) maps)]
     (into [headers] rows)))

(defn write-csv-from-maps 
  "Takes a file (path, name and extension) and a collection of maps
   transforms data (vector of vectors with all values) 
   writes csv file."
  [file maps]
  (->> maps maps->csv-data (write-csv file)))
```

B. Semantic CSV Approach

Alternatively, you can use [`semantic-csv`](https://github.com/metasoarous/semantic-csv) library.
`maps->csv-data` would then become `semantic-csv.core/vectorize`

```
(require '[clojure.data.csv :as csv]
         '[clojure.java.io :as io]
         '[semantic-csv.core :as sc])

(defn write-csv 
  "Takes a file (path, name and extension) and 
   csv-data (vector of vectors with all values) and
   writes csv file."
  [file csv-data] 
  (with-open [writer (io/writer file)]
    (csv/write-csv writer csv-data)))

(defn write-csv-from-maps 
  "Takes a file (path, name and extension) and a collection of maps
   transforms data (vector of vectors with all values) 
   writes csv file."
  [file maps]
  (->> maps sc/vectorize (write-csv file)))
```

--

Finally:

```
(def data
  [{:a "Completed"   :b 1 :c "Friday"  :d 4}
   {:a "Started"     :b 1 :c "Monday"  :d 4}
   {:a "In Progress" :b 1 :c "Sunday"  :d 1}
   {:a "Completed"   :b 3 :c "Tuesday" :d 9}])

(write-csv "/tmp/results.csv" data)
```

Hope that could be useful to someone!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json) to convert the json to a sequence of clojure maps.
2. Use map destructuring to convert to a sequence of strings: `(map #(let [{a :a b :b c :c d :d} %] (str a "," b "," c "," d, "\n")) <your sequence of clojure maps>)`.
3. Dump the sequence of strings to a file

Answer (score 1):

```
(def data [{:a "Completed" :b 1 :c "Friday" :d 4} 
           {:a "Started" :b 1 :c "Monday" :d 4} 
           {:a "In Progress" :b 1 :c "Sunday" :d 1} 
           {:a "Completed" :b 3 :c "Tuesday" :d 9}])

(for [i (range (count data))]
       (if (= i 0) 
        (do 
            (spit "data.csv" (str (clojure.string/join "," (map name (keys (data i)))) "\n") :append true) 
            (spit "data.csv" (str (clojure.string/join "," (vals (data i))) "\n") :append true)) 
        (spit "data.csv" (str (clojure.string/join "," (vals (data i))) "\n") :append true)))
```

To see the results:

```
$ cat data.csv
c,b,d,a
Friday,1,4,Completed
Monday,1,4,Started
Sunday,1,1,In Progress
Tuesday,3,9,Completed
```

This answer is better because this method takes everything from the data and you don't have to hardcode anything. And also this method does not make use of any extra libraries except `clojure.string/join`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this code is not csv,
But If you want to save it as xlsx, this worked for me.

```
  (use 'dk.ative.docjure.spreadsheet)
  (defn save-to-xls [f ms]
    (let [vs (let [-keys (sort (keys (first ms)))
                   ordered-vals (apply juxt -keys)]
               (concat [(map name -keys)]
                       (map ordered-vals ms)))
          wb (create-workbook "sheet1" vs)]
      (save-workbook! f wb))))
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the [clojure-csv](https://github.com/davidsantiago/clojure-csv) library, to easily read and write well-formed csv.